# Merge [amazon-device-farm] with [aws-devicefarm]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

[amazon-device-farm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-device-farm) appears to be a duplicate of [aws-devicefarm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-devicefarm). Can someone merge?

Comment: Also important to note: [tag:amazon-device-farm] has only one follower, 21 questions, and no usage guidance, wheras [tag:aws-devicefarm] has a decent usage guidance, 160 questions, and a handful of followers.

Comment: I'll be doing this separately, 1. synonym from [amazon-device-farm] to  [aws-devicefarm] 2. merge thee tags 3. rename [aws-devicefarm] to [aws-device-farm]. There needs to be a gap of 3 minutes between each tasks... Will be done in 10 mins.